# Google App Engine: how to delete sessions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

is there any way to clean up webapp2 (the framework used in Google App Engine - Python) session  (extras package)?

Comment: I looked into this a little while ago, and while I may have not found the correct answer, my impression was that you have to manually delete sessions.

Answer (score 1):

By default Sessions are only stored but not deleted after they are expired. There seems to be only a predefined servlet in Java.

For Python I found the Project [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions) which offers also a simlar functionality like in Java. You have to define a [cron job](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/demo/cron.yaml) that calls some [cleanup routine](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/demo/cleanup_sessions.py).

Cronjob:

```
cron:
- description: daily session cleanup
  url: /cleanup_sessions
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

Cleanup routine:

```
from gaesessions import delete_expired_sessions
while not delete_expired_sessions():
    pass
```